Is $z^{t+1}$ a homotopy between $z$ and $z^2$?
I am recently learning about homotopy and mapping degree and I have been very confused over a simple example.
Consider the function $z$ mapping from the unit circle  $S^1$ in the complex plane to $
\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$.
I am looking at the function defined by $z^{t+1}$, where $t$ ranges from 0 to 1. Is the function $z^{t+1}$ continuous on the product space $[0,1] \times S^1$?
If it were, then that would imply $z$ and $z^2$ are homotopic and thus they would need to have the same winding number, which they clearly do not. But I don't see how $z^{t+1}$ can be discontinuous since everything looks continuous.

Have you looked at an actual example?  Try $t = 1/2$: think about what you want $z^{3/2}$ to mean when $z$ runs over the unit circle and check yourself whether your $z^{3/2}$ is continuous on all of $S^1$.

The power function for complex numbers is defined as $$z^{t+1}=e^{(t+1)\text{Log}(z)}$$
If $t$ is not an integer, this function will be discontinuous at all points in the ray corresponding to the branch of the logarithm used. This ray will intersect the unit circle in some point, making the function discontinuous and thus not a homotopy.
